# JBOSS MySQL connection pool

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss

Hi I've created a MySQL connection pool on my JBOSS AS7, and I've a stateless session bean using it to get some data from my database. The question is, after the bean get all the needed data, do I have to call any function to inform that the connection is no longer needed for that bean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Bean should be annotated with a TansactionAttribute- annotation. In this you can define the behavior of Transactions. For Example a

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

opens a new connection at every call. This is what you are needing.

Other Example: a

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.SUPPORTS)
```

annotation uses an existing (open) connection and so on.

Result: No, the container manages the connections to the database it is not needed to call an other method.

See Oracle Doc:
[Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncij.html)